# Is there an example of a field K and a field extension L/K for which there is an automorphism of L/K that does not let K fixed?

Tags: abstract-algebra

We know that for an extension of the rational numbers, the rationals must stay fixed. So is there an example where K is not fixed.

Comment: $K(X, Y) / K(X)$ interchanging $X$ and $Y$ for some field $K$?

Comment: When you write "automorphism of $\;L/K\;$" it is usually understood that the automorphism fixes $\;K\;$ ...You must mean an automorphims of $\;L\;$, simply...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are general procedures for constructing such examples. Let $K=Q(a)$ where $a$ is the root of some polynomial, $p(x)$, that is irreducible over $Q$. There is an isomorphism, $h$, on $K$ that fixes $Q$ but sends $a$ to another root of $p(x)$, $b$.

Now define $L$ to be the splitting field of $p(x)$ over $Q$. We can extend $h$ to an automorphism, $\bar h$, on $L$.

However, $h(a)\neq a$ so $h$ has not fixed $K$. If you want $h(K)\neq K$ as well, we simply need ensure that $K(a)$ does not split over $Q$.

For a specific example, let $p(x)=x^3-2$ and let $a=\sqrt[3]{2}$. There is an isomorphism from $Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ to $Q(\omega\sqrt[3]{2})$ where $\omega$ is a complex cube root of unity. Since $\omega$ is complex, this isomorphism clearly doesn't fix $Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$. But it can be extended to an automorphism on $Q(\sqrt[3]{2},\omega\sqrt[3]{2})$, the splitting field of $x^3-2$ over $Q$.